# Why does this return `nil` or the array?

Tags: ruby

It seems that the following code randomly returns the expected array for `d`, or `nil`.

```
def f arg
  arg
end
def g *args
  args
end

x,y,z = [true, 'two', false]
if a = f(x) and b = f(y) and c = f(z) then
  d = g(a,b,c) 
end
p d
```

Comment: Statements like `a = f(x)` are truthy; if the result of evaluating the assignment is truthy, then that will evaluate to `true`.  Is that what you intended?  You may have intended to do `a == f(x)`.

Comment: Randomly? `d` should always be `nil` (as expected) and it is for me (2.2.2).

Comment: If you find you often write `a=b` when you mean `a==b`, you could get into the habit of writing `a.eql?(b)`.

Comment: @Makoto: I'm sure that's intentional however I think OP is maybe confused by uninitialized local variables being `nil`.

Comment: @cremno, recall that a reference to an uninitialized local variable (as opposed to an uninitialized instance variable) raises an exception. Whoops. sorry I didn't read it carefully enough. I see it's in an `if`, so it is initialized to `nil`.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. It always returns `nil`, as expected.

Comment: Makato, I did intend that to be a = f(x).  Cremno, So can you do the expression d = g(a,b,c) but not in the boolean expression?

Comment: `x,y,z = [true, 'two', false]` is inconsistent and confusing. You should do `x, y, z = true, 'two', false`.

Comment: @sawa That may be true, however it does not address the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `=` operator performs assignment. It's different from the equality operator (`==`), which you would use to compare two values.

Here's a typical example of how these are used:

```
def speak(name)
  if name == 'Hal'
    puts "I can't do that, Dave."
  end
end

myName = 'Hal'
speak(myName)
```

Then the output is:

```
I can't do that, Dave.
```

You're using `=` in the condition of your `if` statement, where you probably meant to use `==`.  In `irb` this generates a warning like this:

```
(irb):9: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
```

So you're probably wondering, *If I used the wrong operator, why does my code work at all?*

Your code can still execute because

1. Assignments are expressions, meaning they return values.
2. All values can be evaluated as "true" or "false" (truthy or falsey).

What this means is that, in your code, `a = f(x)`, `b = f(y)`, and `c = f(z)` are each *returning a value* in addition to assigning a variable.

In each case, the value returned is the same as what is assigned: `true`, `"two"`, and `false`, respectively. Therefore, your `if` statement is evaluating this condition:

```
true and "two" and false
```

In Ruby, all values are "truthy" except `false` and `nil`.

The string "two" is truthy, because it is neither `false` nor `nil`. However, the `false` is of course, "falsey," meaning that the whole expression evaluates as false, and the body of the `if` statement does not execute, so that `g` is never called, and the value of `d` remains unchanged.

Comment: Amar in the code a = f(x), etc.  I was trying to return the value true and assign a variable.  My question is why  d = g(a,b,c) not working like the other similar variable assignments.

Comment: @JohnLarkin `d = g(a,b,c)` should not execute at all, since `c = f(z)` evaluates as `false`, making the whole condition `false`.

Comment: Oh thanks amar I get it now.  That is why I can do d = g(a,b,c) on it's own.